# servo controller publisher

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i create a subscribe sevo controller like this tutorial [wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Servo Controller](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Servo%20Controller) and i want to create a publisher on my PC.
i try with this code, but it doesnt work. could you help me please?

```
  int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        ros::init(argc, argv, "servo_publisher");
        ros::NodeHandle n;
        ros::Publisher servo_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::UInt16>("servo", 1000);
        ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
        int count = 0;
        while(ros::ok())
        {
            std_msgs::UInt16 cmd_msg;
            cmd_msg.data = 10;
            ROS_INFO("%i",cmd_msg.data);
            servo_pub.publish(cmd_msg);
            ros::spin();
            loop_rate.sleep();
            ++count;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233556/servo-controller-publisher/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should be a  `ros::spinOnce();` instead of `ros::spin();`

`ros::spin()` is spinning continuously and thus you should only receive the very first message.

Check out [the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning) for more info.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-05-04**:
thank you very much